# A short paragraph meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

> In considering the life of Shakespeare, we have at our disposal a fair number of facts; but on these facts the industry of commentators has constructed an additional mass of great magnitude and complexity. **It is therefore the duty of the historian with only a limited space at his disposal to keep his eyes steadily upon the established facts and,** **without being superior or disdainful, to turn toward speculation or surmise**, however ingenious or laborious, a face of tempered but obdurate scepticism.

-*History of English Literature* by Edward Albert

Author says first that it is the duty of the historian to always use established facts but then he adds 'and to turn toward speculation and surmise without being superior or disdainful'.

Isn't the second part contradicting the first one? Like he meant that they should use established facts but they can also use speculation or surmise without being superior or disdainful'. He could add **not**  before *to turn toward.*

'without being superior or disdainful' is a non-essential clause, so 'and' is working here as a conjunction adding 'established facts clause' to 'turn toward the speculation clause'- that's what I understand.
And, 'Turn toward' means perhaps to move in the direction of.

Comment: No, it isn't a contradiction. He says that you should "turn [a face of... scepticism] toward speculation and surmise."

Comment: It's very tortuous phrasing. I had to read the highlighted text *three times* before it finally dawned on me how to parse it. What it's saying is the conscientious historian should *turn a face of tempered but obdurate scepticism* towards *speculation or surmise* (no matter how ingenious or laborious that speculation might be). I wouldn't recommend such circumlocutory text for learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a confusingly written sentence.

The confusion comes from the insertion of the clause "however ingenious or laborious."

Removing that phrase and another similar parenthetical, we get, "...to keep his eyes steadily upon the established facts and...to turn toward speculation or surmise...a face of tempered but obdurate scepticism."

It is not that the historian must himself "turn toward speculation or surmise."  It's that the historian must "turn [a face of skepticism] toward speculation of surmise."

Put more simply, *the historian must focus on the established facts, and always be skeptical of speculation and surmise.  And he or she should do this even when it's difficult.  And he or she should not be superior or disdainful.

Comment: I can't understand why he wrote 'a face of tempered but obdurate scepticism' after 'speculation and surmise'. ' A face of tempered...' is the object of verb 'turn' and ' speculation or surmise' is the object of preposition 'toward'. If he had written in a standard Word order it would have been much more easy to understand what he meant.

Comment: @RADS, I associate this kind of phrasing with early- or pre-20th century English, and with texts that were translated into English.  There was a time (like in the early, or pre-20th century) when English was not so culturally dominant, and highly educated English speakers were fluent in continental European languages.  It's possible that this style shows the influence of a different language where this kind of sentence structure makes more sense.